How to dynamically inject a service based on the output of another service
I have 2 possible implementations of an interface, and in my Program.cs I want to dynamically inject the right one. However, the logic of which one to inject depends on another service being used. Previously in I was doing this:
services.AddScoped<IOtherService, OtherService>();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var otherService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOtherService>();
if (otherService.SomeValue == "Value1")
{
    services.AddScoped<IDynamicService, DynamicService1>();
}
else if (otherService.SomeValue == "Value2")
{
    services.AddScoped<IDynamicService, DynamicService2>();
}

This gives a warning that BuildServiceProvider() shouldn't be called like this because it could result in an additional copy of singleton services being created. I found several answers on the Internet (example) saying that the solution is to use the Options Pattern and AddOptions().Configure(), but I can't quite understand how that works in my case.
Using this example:
services.AddOptions<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.Configure<IManageJwtAuthentication>((opts,jwtAuthManager)=>{
    opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        AudienceValidator = jwtAuthManager.AudienceValidator,
        // More code here...
    };
});

This seems to sets up some configuration details on the injected IManageJwtAuthentication. But I don't need to just configure some property on my injected service, I need to change what service is being injected. I don't see how I can do something like the example above unless this Configure() method could also be passed my IServiceCollection so that I can call services.AddScoped() from within that context. In a few different attempts at similar things, I wasn't ever seeing my .Configure() method called at all.
Am I right that Options Pattern is the way to go for something like this? I don't quite understand the relationship between Options Pattern and accessing other services from within my Program.cs; what I've read suggests that Options Pattern is a way to load and inject subsets of Configuration/settings.

How about using implementation factory? Use overload for service registration method that supply IServiceProvider over func:
services.AddScoped<DynamicService1>();
services.AddScoped<DynamicService2>();
services.AddScoped<IDynamicService>(sp =>
{
    var evaluationDependency = sp.GetRequiredService<IDependencyEvaluationService>();
    var value = evaluationDependency.GetEvaluationValue();

    if (value == "Value1")
    {
        return sp.GetRequiredService<DynamicService1>();
    }
    else
    {
        return sp.GetRequiredService<DynamicService2>();
    }
});

Caching the evaluation result
Quite a downside to approach above is that evaluation is performed every time IDynamicService is requested. So, if evaluation is a time costly process, say some IO operation, we can always cache the result. At that point, it's probably better to use a dedicated factory anyway:
public interface IDynamicServiceFactory
{
    IDynamicService CreateDynamicService();
}

public class DynamicServiceFactory : IDynamicServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IDependencyEvaluationService dependencyEvaluationService;
    private readonly IDependency1Service dependency1Service;
    private readonly IDependency2Service dependency2Service;

    public DynamicServiceFactory(
        IDependencyEvaluationService dependencyEvaluationService,
        IDependency1Service dependency1Service,
        IDependency2Service dependency2Service)
    {
        this.dependencyEvaluationService = dependencyEvaluationService;
        this.dependency1Service = dependency1Service;
        this.dependency2Service = dependency2Service;
    }

    public IDynamicService CreateDynamicService()
    {
        var value = dependencyEvaluationService.GetEvaluationValue();
        if (value == "Value1")
        {
            return new DynamicService1(dependency1Service);
        }
        else
        {
            return new DynamicService2(dependency2Service);
        }
    }
}

service getting the value (presumably long-running operation):
public interface IDependencyEvaluationService
{
    string GetEvaluationValue();
}

public class DependencyEvaluationService : IDependencyEvaluationService
{
    private readonly IDependencyEvaluationStore dependencyEvaluationStore;

    public DependencyEvaluationService(IDependencyEvaluationStore dependencyEvaluationStore)
    {
        this.dependencyEvaluationStore = dependencyEvaluationStore;
    }

    public string GetEvaluationValue()
    {
        if (dependencyEvaluationStore.TryGetValue(out var value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        // Some long operation.
        value = "value2";

        dependencyEvaluationStore.SetValue(value);

        return value;
    }
}

and store which holds the result value:
public interface IDependencyEvaluationStore
{
    bool TryGetValue(out string value);

    void SetValue(string value);
}

public class DependencyEvaluationInMemoryStore : IDependencyEvaluationStore
{
    private static readonly object _lock = new ();

    private string _value;
    private bool _hasValueSet;

    public bool TryGetValue(out string value)
    {
        if (_hasValueSet)
        {
            value = _value;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void SetValue(string value)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _value = value;
            _hasValueSet = true;
        }
    }
}

More services overall, but simplified registration:
services.AddScoped<IDependencyEvaluationService, DependencyEvaluationService>();
services.AddTransient<IDynamicServiceFactory, DynamicServiceFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<IDependencyEvaluationStore, DependencyEvaluationInMemoryStore>();
services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IDynamicServiceFactory>().CreateDynamicService());

Final words
Both of these approaches have a weakness that it becomes a pain to maintain correct dependencies needed to create service implementations. While it is not that big of a hassle for simple scenarios, it can become burdensome for more complex services. I'd advise straight away injecting factory and resolving correct implementation at the caller site, if possible, of course.

That looks good right up until it calls the constructor on the services. That seems a bit confusing that the lambda would return an instance of the class with new() rather than just the type, since normally AddScoped just requires the class, not an instance. I have lots of dependencies in those services; having to find each one to pass into the constructor would be a lot.

@Prolog, I hope you don't mind, but I updated your first example a bit. It's now a bit simpler and addresses Gendolkari's remarks.

That said, calling a service during construction is problematic (because this and this). For instance, assume GetEvaluationValue and you'll start to see the issue.

The simplest version of this seems to work well for my case. My DependencyEvaluationService here is a simple TenantProvider that just looks at configurations to determine which instance of the code base is running. The code to determine the service could have been pulled into Program.cs directly, but it would have required moving or copying the logic that reads the configurations to get the correct Tenant.

I ended up with this syntax (found on Reddit):
services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService().SomeValue switch
{
"Value1" => sp.GetRequiredService(),
"Value2" => sp.GetRequiredService(),
_ => throw new NotImplementedException()
});

How about this approach?
services.AddScoped<IDynamicService, DynamicService1>();
services.AddScoped<IDynamicService, DynamicService2>();

Instead of dynamically registering the services, register all of them.
Add a service like this:
public class DynamicServiceResolver
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IDynamicService> services;

    public DynamicServiceResolver(
        IEnumerable<IDynamicService> services,
        // You can also inject any dependent services here to help choose the correct one.
    )
    {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public IDynamicService GetService()
    {
        // Here, find and return the desired service based on your logic.
    }
}

// In Program.cs
services.AddScoped<DynamicServiceResolver>();

You can inject DynamicServiceResolver to get the desired service.
+ Given the additional context, here’s another approach you might find useful:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var sc = new ServiceCollection();

sc.AddKeyedSingleton<IService, Service1>("internal");
sc.AddKeyedSingleton<IService, Service2>("internal");
sc.AddSingleton<IService, ServiceResolver>();

var services = sc.BuildServiceProvider();

var service = services.GetRequiredService<IService>();

service.DoSomething();

interface IService
{
    void DoSomething();
}
class Service1 : IService
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
class Service2 : IService
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}

class ServiceResolver : IService
{
    readonly IService service;
    public ServiceResolver([FromKeyedServices("internal")] IEnumerable<IService> services)
    {
        service = GetService(services);
    }
    IService GetService(IEnumerable<IService> services) => services.First();
    public void DoSomething() => service.DoSomething();
}


I believe there’s no issue with the Resolver implementing IService, since it essentially serves the purpose of providing a single IService.

Thanks for the suggestion. I've done this before elsewhere when a service definitely couldn't be determined during application startup. I was hoping to avoid it here both because it's extra code anywhere my service is needed, and because this is an existing codebase with the service already injected in a lot of places; they would all have to be changed to do this.

@GendoIkari edited.

Additionally, if you need to register services based on settings from appsettings.json or similar configuration files, you can access the .Configuration in the builder and use it to register services dynamically. If the service that needs to be resolved changes at runtime, you can use the method described above.
